# Create macro using xparse that creates spaces between arguments

Tags: spacing, conditionals, xparse

When I write units in math mode, I separate them using `\,` eg: `$3 \; kg \, m^2$`

I want to create a macro that does this for me, so I used `xparse` like this:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand \units{O{}O{}O{}}{\;#1 \,#2 \,#3}
```

The problem is that if I only specify one argument, I still get 2 extra spaces because my macro skips the arguments but not the `\,`.

What I would like is that my macro skips the extra `\,` commands if I only specify 1 or 2 arguments.

Comment: do you really set kg in math italic?

Comment: Why don't you use siunitx?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  For units you should defintely use `siunitx` package. But, in general to accomplish what you want you can either detect that an empty paramater was given and only add the `\,` spacing if the paramater is not empty, or switch to using the `o` or `g` paramter type (and then use `\IfNoValueTF` to detect missing parameters).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fundamentally you want to condition on the existence of your optional arguments. In [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) this is done using `\IfValueTF` with the `TF` being optional on whether or not you need a `T`rue or `F`alse branch.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand\units{ o o o }{%
  \IfValueT{#1}{\;#1}%
  \IfValueT{#2}{\,#2}%
  \IfValueT{#3}{\,#3}%
}

\begin{document}

This pumpkin weighs $3\units[\text{kg}]$. That's heavy!

I can run $12\units[\text{m}][\text{s}^{-1}]$. That's fast!

Something ridiculous $1\units[a][b][c]$. That's ridiculous!

Something $5\units$ something else.

\end{document}
```

In general, units should be set like regular text.

---

A far better approach would be to use [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareSIUnit{\aaa}{a}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bbb}{b}
\DeclareSIUnit{\ccc}{c}

\begin{document}

This pumpkin weighs $\SI{3}{\kilogram}$. That's heavy!

I can run $\SI{12}{\metre\per\second}$. That's fast!

Something ridiculous $\SI{1}{\aaa \bbb \ccc}$. That's ridiculous!

Something $5$ something else.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help with `xparse`, I'll definitely use `siunitx` from now on though.

Answer (score 5):

What if you have more than three units? Here units are separated by spaces, then the macro takes care of using thin spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand\units{>{\SplitList{ }}m}{%
  \ProcessList{#1}{\addunit}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\addunit}{m}{%
  \,\mathrm{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

This pumpkin weighs $3\units{kg}$. That's heavy!

I can run $12\units{m s^{-1}}$. That's fast!

Something ridiculous $1\units{a b c}$. That's ridiculous!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, `siunitx` is far better.

Comment: I think I prefer your way of using `xparse`, but as has been mentioned by pretty much everyone `siunitx` is better so I'll use that instead.